# ifstream not working

Tags: c++

I'm trying to open a file using ifstream, but no matter what solutions I find that I've tried, nothing seems to work; my program always outputs "unable to open". Below is my code in its entirety. Any help at all is appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    string junk;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("somefile.txt");

    if(fin.is_open())
    {
        fin >> junk;
        cout << junk;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "unable to open" << endl;
    }

    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Also, the contents of somefile.txt, which is in the same directory as the created executable is the following:

```
SOME
FILE
```

Comment: Are you running the executable from the same directory?

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, and you start the program from within the IDE, the working directory of your program will be set to the project directory, not the executable's directory. Is this the case here?

Comment: hmjd - I certainly am
Cameron - No, the directories are the same (I'm using Code::Blocks anyhow)

Comment: @user1903336, add `strerror(errno)` to the output. I bet you are not.

Comment: Also, when I run the program using command-line arguments to get the string name, it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

As some commenters have suggested, it could easily be that the file truly doesn't exist, because you're looking for it in the wrong place.  Try using an absolute path to the file rather than just assuming it's looking where you expect.

And output a more helpful error message using `strerror(errno)`.

```
// ...
fin.open("C:\\path\\to\\somefile.txt");

// ...
else
{
    cout << "unable to open: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
}
```